Path space with submanifold boundary conditions ($\mathbb{S}^1 \subset \mathbb{S}^2$)
Say I have a manifold $M$ and a submanifold $Q \subset M$. I am interested in the space of paths:
$$P(M;Q) = \{\gamma : [0,1] \xrightarrow{\mathcal{C}^0} M \, \mid \, \gamma(0), \gamma(1) \in Q\}$$
I am not aware of any results about such spaces, so maybe the following argument can be obtained in a simpler way. I would like to know whether the following is correct or not:
Say $M = \mathbb{S}^2 = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \, \mid \, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\}$, and $Q$ is the equator given by $Q = \{x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$. I would like to show that $P(M;Q)$ is of infinite-type (its homology is infinite-dimensional). Is there any way to do this?

The following is wrong, as pointed out in the comments, I'm just keeping it for completeness
The reason I think so is because: fix two points $a,b \in Q$. Then, I'm pretty sure that, up to homotopy, a path between $a$ and $b$ is only determined by its winding number around the equator $Q$, verifying that $P(M; \{a,b\}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.
If we keep $a$ fixed but change $b$ into some $c$, then I think we can just homotope any path between $a$ and $c$ into a path between $a$ and $b$, so that in general:
$$\{\gamma : [0,1] \to M \, \mid \, \gamma(0) = a, \gamma(1) \in Q\} \cong \mathbb{Z}$$
First question: is this correct so far?
Second question: can I now directly conclude that $P(M;Q)$ is of infinite-type? If the above is correct, then I know that there are $\mathbb{Z}$ homotopy classes of paths starting at $a \in Q$, and ending somewhere else in $Q$.
Am I allowed to also move $a$ on $Q$ by homotopy? In which case, I would get $P(M;Q) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.
If not, then I guess I would get $P(M;Q) \cong \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{S}^1$, since I get a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ for each point in the equator.

I don’t see why there’s a winding number for paths between $a$ and $b$. You can always unwind it in the “third dimension” $z$.

While staying on the sphere though? We only have two dimensions on the sphere, so from a naive drawing I thought that we could distinguish paths by how many times they crossed the equator? (Though I may indeed be wrong. But I don't see how to unwind such a path)

Yes, you can unwind it on the sphere because it is simply connected. In particular, take two paths between $a$ and $b$ and join them at $a$ and $b$. That gives you a closed loop on the sphere. It can be deformed to the trivial loop at $a$ because the sphere is simply connected.

I agree with this, but then ultimately I'm confused. Because in essence, this tells us that the based path space of $\mathbb{S}^2$ is zero. So in particular, $P(M;Q) = 0$ in my question.

But then, by the same reasoning, why could I not argue that the free loop space of $\mathbb{S}^2$ is zero? I want to argue the same way that you did: every loop on the sphere is contractible, and since we can move them around up to homotopy, all loops on $\mathbb{S}^2$ should be homotopic. But I know that the free loop space of $\mathbb{S}^2$ is not supposed to be zero; which is why I'm confused I guess.

Free loop space isn’t defined as space of all loops up to homotopy. It’s just the space of all loops.

I see! Thank you. So I guess my confusion from the start is that I've been asking things to be homotopic when there is no reason to do so. So I guess that the space of paths starting from $a$ and ending elsewhere in $Q$ is not necessarily zero then. I simply have no idea what it is

Evaluation at the endpoints yields a fibration $\Omega M\rightarrow P(M;Q)\rightarrow Q\times Q$. You could try running a Serre spectral sequence on that.

As illustrated by the failure of your approach, it's usually very difficult to argue "intuitively" about the homology of mapping spaces. Instead, to get a hold of homology, other techniques are required and in this case you're in luck: The space $P(M; Q)$ sits in a pullback square
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    P(M; Q) @>>> PM \\
    @VVV @VV(\mathrm{ev}_0, \mathrm{ev}_1)V\\
    Q \times Q @>>(\iota, \iota)> M \times M
\end{CD}
where $PM$ is the (free) path space of $M$, $\mathrm{ev}_t$ is the evaluation map sending a path $\gamma\colon I \to M$ to $\gamma(t)$, and $\iota\colon Q \hookrightarrow M$ is the inclusion.
Since the map at the right is a fibration with fibre $\Omega M$, so is the one at the left, and this gives us a way to tackle the problem using the Serre spectral sequence. Specializing to $M = S^2$ and $Q = S^1$ and working with $\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}\F_2$-coefficients since the base is not simply connected (perhaps one can show that the fibration at the left is orientable, but for our purpose this suffices [Edit: Thorgott pointed out to me that pullbacks of orientable fibrations are again orientable, and the fibration at the right is orientable since $S^2 \times S^2$ is simply-connected, so this is true]) we obtain a spectral sequence
$$
    E^2_{p, q} = H_p(S^1 \times S^1; H_q(\Omega S^2; \F_2)) \Rightarrow H_{p + q}(P(S^2; S^1); \F_2)
$$
Since $H_n(\Omega S^2; \F_2) \cong \F_2$ for all $n \geq 0$, we find that
$$
    E^2_{p, q} \cong \begin{cases}
        \F_2 & p \in \{0, 2\}, q \geq 0 \\
        \F_2^2 & p = 1, q \geq 0 \\
        0 & \text{else}
    \end{cases}
$$
In particular no differential can affect the $E^2_{1, *}$-column, so we conclude that $\dim_{\F_2} H_n(P(S^2; S^1); \F_2) \geq 2$ for all $n > 0$. It follows that $H_*(P(S^2; S^1); \mathbb{Z})$ cannot be of finite type.

This is a really great, and clear answer! Indeed, I tried to go way too naively about it when really, Serre tells you everything you need to know. This is a great lesson. Thank you very much :)

@Azur Thank you! I somehow forgot that $H_2(S^1 \times S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, so the strong conclusion about the dimension of $H_*(P(S^2; S^1); \mathbb{F}_2)$ might not after all be true, but the conclusion that it is not of finite type still holds.

I do have one small correction (I think?) which does not change the finality, but which is just one more step in the argument. The projection $PM \xrightarrow{(ev_0,ev_1)} M\times M$ does not straight up define the loop-path fibration. Instead, we need to restrict the base space to the diagonal $\Delta_M \subset M\times M$, and then we get a fibration $\Omega M \to PM \to \Delta_M$.

That's for the right side of your pullback triangle. Pulling that back to the left side, you get $\Omega M \to P_Q M \to \Delta_Q$ (well, the fiber is actually $\Omega_Q M$, so I guess one needs to show this is infinite-dimensional). In any case, this thing is a fibration, so that you can derive a spectral sequence, and reach the same conclusion. (Except now, only the columns $p \in {0,1}$ are non-zero, since the base space is $\mathbb{S}^1$, instead of $\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{S}^1$)

Ah wait no, I mixed stuff up. The fibration with base space $\Delta M$ is $\Omega M \to LM \to \Delta_M$, where $LM$ is the free loop space, my bad. So I do indeed need to consider the fibration $\Omega M \to P(M;Q) \to M\times M$. Though I do not understand why it is indeed a fibration (unless I force a choice of base point $q \in Q$ for each of these three spaces, as Thorgott explained; but then I'm no longer calculating the homology of the free path space, which is what I wanted).

@Azur The fibres of $(\mathrm{ev}_0, \mathrm{ev}_1)$ are all homotopy equivalent since it is a fibration, so I can in particular pick some $(x, x) \in M$ as the point to take the fibre over, and this fibre is just $\Omega_x M$. As for $P(M; Q) \to M \times M$, the only map of that form I see is composing $P(M; Q) \to Q \times Q$ with the inclusion into $M \times M$. This is a fibration iff $Q = M$, but I don't understand why you'd want it to be. If you meant $P(M; Q) \to Q \times Q$, this follows from stability of fibrations under pullback.

Ah, I see your point indeed. Basically, in the fibration ? $\to P(M;Q) \to Q\times Q$, I was concerned by the fact that if the base point $(q_1,q_2)$ did not lie in the diagonal ($q_1 \ne q_2$) then the fiber was just a path space between two base points, and not a loop space $\Omega_{pt} M$. However, as you have pointed out, all fibers are homotopically equivalent to each other? Which I guess settles it
